# JavaScript - Accepting only certain values for decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number field to which I need to apply certain conditions with pure JS or jQuery:

- Max 30
- Min -30
- Only 2 digits after the point, example 2.25
- So possible values are like this (2.00 / 2.25 / 2.50/ 2.75 / 3.00...)

I managed to do so unless for the last condition that should accept only values .00 or .25 or .50 or .75
Here is my code:

```js
var t_myField   = false;
var myField_min = -30;
var myField_max = 30;
$('#myField').focus(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this)
    t_myField = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
            if (($this.val() < myField_min || $this.val() > myField_max) && $this.val().length != 0)
            {
                if ($this.val() < myField_min)
                {
                    $this.val(myField_min)
                }
                if ($this.val() > myField_max)
                {
                    $this.val(myField_max)
                }
            }
        }, 50)
});

$('#myField').on("keyup", function (e)
{
    // Replacer , by .
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '.'));

    // Allow only float numeric values (positif & negatif)
    var self = $(this);
    self.val(self.val().replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g, ''));
    if (e.which != 46 && e.which != 45 && e.which != 46 && !(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Allow max 2 digits after decimals for certain fields
    match      = (/(\d{0,2})[^.]*((?:\.\d{0,2})?)/g).exec(this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
    this.value = match[1] + match[2];
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="myField" id="myField" class="myField">
```

JSFIDDLE => https://jsfiddle.net/Cartha/vq65Lypj/5/

**[EDIT]**
Control should be on keyup. This is why I can't use html5 attributes like min/max/step...

Comment: Step by 0.25 means you want to increase the value of textbox by 0.25 on a particular event?

Comment: It sounds like a range input would possibly suit your needs better.

Comment: By step I mean: not possible values after the point than these: nothing or .00 or .25 or .50 or .75

Comment: Please re-check my answer. The web component makes this really easy and readable. Combining `input type="number"` with some Javascript checks and value replacement on `input` event does a perfect job here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan A customized built-in `input type="number"` I'd say is the best approach here. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `%` operator like `x % 0.25 == 0 ? true : false`

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. OP's question might be unclear but as far as I know this validates the step correctly.

Comment: Could you explain more please or better, give a complete answer ? JSFiddle ? thanks :)

Comment: @Cartha to help you get started the operator used is called the modulus operator (the % sign). Check [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm) for a quick overview of what it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
let myField = document.getElementById('myField');

myField.addEventListener('keypress', onlyNumbers,{passive: false});
myField.addEventListener('change', checkInput);

function onlyNumbers(e) {
    if (!isNumberKey(e)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function isNumberKey(e) {
    return (e.which <= 31 || (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || e.which === 45 || e.which === 46);
}

function checkInput(e) {
    let x = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    if (!isNaN(x)) {
      if (x > 30) {
        x = 30;
      } else if (x < -30) {
        x = -30;
      } else if (x % 0.25 !== 0) {
        x = Math.round(x / 0.25) * 0.25;
      }
      e.target.value = x.toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

This will allow only numbers with 0.25 steps.

Digit-only algorithm has been improved to completely prevent other type of input to be displayed (your code shows the forbidden input and then erases it).

This is the basic idea, a lot of other improvements can be made. For example, to always show two decimals (EX. 2.00 instead of 2), make an animation, etc. Currently, the check is set to happen after focus ends.

- NOTE: Little extra improvements made in last edit.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ernestostifano/fcx5jgb0/) (I don't know how to embed it to the answer)

Comment: Upvoted. This is a good start. And Yes, lot of omprovements could be made :)

Comment: I have just edited my last answer to add some of those improvements for you. Check it out. It should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a web component here. I'll show you the basic setup for a customized built-in with a component that already works and does not involve fumbling with `$(document).ready()` or `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
class DecimalInput extends HTMLInputElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      const val = parseFloat(this.value),
        min = parseFloat(this.min),
        max = parseFloat(this.max),
        step = parseFloat(this.step);
        
      if (val%step !== 0) {
        this.value = Math.round(val/step) * step
      }
      if (val > max) {
        this.value = max
      }
      if (val < min) {
        this.value = min
      }
      
      this.value = Number(this.value).toFixed(2, 10);
    })
  }
}

customElements.define('decimal-input', DecimalInput, { extends: 'input' })
```

```html
<input type="number" is="decimal-input" min="-30" max="30" step="0.25" value="0" />
```

This component is already quite close to your requirements. Use it to do our own refinements based on this.

Comment: This code accept values superior to 30 (try 30.5), do not limit digitals to 2 after the point, and accept any values that required after the point.

Comment: The code had some errors which I fixed now. My answer should only serve as a starting point to show how you could approach the problem using a web component.