# Prevent user from inputting a number outside of value range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this stack question as the foundation of my validation input. I have a range slider where the user can input a number inbetween 8 and 24. If the user inputs a number more than 24, it should go to 24. If the user inputs a number less than 8, it should go to 8.

The issue I have is that if the user inputs a number more than 24, it automatically goes to 8. Any thoughts?

[Prevent user from typing in input at max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271242/prevent-user-from-typing-in-input-at-max-value)

```
$('#interestValue').on('keyup keydown', function(e){
   if ($(this).val() > 24 
        && e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
        && e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
       ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).val(24);
       doMath();
    }

     if ($(this).val() < 8
        && e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
        && e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
       ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).val(8);
       doMath();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have answered a very similar question two days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305302/javascript-accepting-only-certains-values-for-decimals/54305706#54305706

Comment: I feel like the `input` event would be a better approach, rather than keyup and down.

Comment: The `input` event covers the up/down arrow button that Chrome and other browsers drop into number fields.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to needing to make sure you're comparing numbers instead of strings, you can't safely do this on `keyup`, `keydown` or `input` -- since those events fire per keystroke, it would be impossible for the user to input (for example) "23", because when they type the first "2" it'll immediately change into an "8".

Use the `change` event instead, which lets the user complete their intended input before you start changing it from underneath them.  (This also allows you to simplify your code since you no longer need to check for 'backspace' and 'delete' key events.)

```js
$('#interestValue').on('change', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   let val = Number($(this).val()); // ensure you're not accidentally comparing strings
   if (val > 24) {
       $(this).val(24);
    } else if (val < 8) {
       $(this).val(8);
    } else if (isNaN(val)) {
       console.log("Input wasn't a number... you probably want to handle this case")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="interestValue">
```

Comment: My issue with this is I have an ajax function which calculates my formula immediately upon input, so the user can still enter "9999" until they hit enter. Is there any way to still validate this so it still triggers when the user doesn't hit enter?

Comment: @chronotrigga Probably that approach doesn't make sense. How do you know the user is finished entering?

Comment: You shouldn't call that ajax function on every keystroke either, for the exact same reason.   "2" might be invalid input, or it might be the first digit of valid input; it's impossible for your code to know the difference unless you wait for the user to finish.

Comment: I see what you guys mean now that it would be impossible to enter 23 for validation since user types in the first "2" and the event fires.. hm... maybe it is best to just default it to the minimum 8 using keyup etc

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend creating a native web component here. I'll show you the basic setup for a customized built-in with a component that already works and that has no external dependencies:

```js
class DecimalInput extends HTMLInputElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      const val = parseFloat(this.value),
            min = parseFloat(this.min),
            max = parseFloat(this.max),
            step = parseFloat(this.step);
            
      if (val%step !== 0) {
        this.value = Math.round(val/step) * step
      }
      if (val > max) {
        this.value = max
      }
      if (val < min) {
        this.value = min
      }
    })
  }
}

customElements.define('decimal-input', DecimalInput, { extends: 'input' })
```

```html
<label><input type="number" is="decimal-input" min="8" max="24" step="1" value="16" /> Allows input from 8-24</label>
<hr />
<label><input type="number" is="decimal-input" min="0" max="1024" step="16" value="16" /> Allows input from 0-1024, in 16-steps</label>
```

This component is already quite close to your requirements. Use it to do your own refinements based on this.

Comment: I saw your comment and appreciate the answer. I know that you're using the change event here which means the event fires after the user is done inputting. Any way to validate this during input? My formula calculation does everything in real-time during input.

Comment: As @Daniel Beck said, that does not make sense. How is a user supposed to enter `21`? With your approach, the user types `2` and that immediately gets replaced by your `min` value.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Hm. Maybe the best option is to just force the min value. Just thought there would be a different way but I see!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend processing the user's value with another event, like 'blur'. 
With blur event you can trigger the calculation when the user changes focus to another field, its easier to control because you wait for user input before trying other stuff. Or you can always try using a setTimeout either inside the event function, or in an external function that validates current user's input value. Gotta be careful with this one though, its highly possible that the current inputted value would be a previous inputted one from the user.

Answer (score -1):

I thought I would post my answer here if it helps anyone. I was able to get this work -- not in the most dev-friendly way but in a good hack.

```
$('#interestValue').on('keyup keydown', function(e){

    if ($(this).val() > 24 
        && e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
        && e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
    ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).val(24);
       doMath();
    }

     if ($(this).val() < 8 && $(this).val() > 2
        && e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
        && e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
       ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).val(8);
       doMath();
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve any of the problems with your original code; you're still potentially comparing strings instead of numbers, and you're still changing the user's input out from under them while they try to type...